# Running Vue3 Jest tests fails after upgrading Inertia.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, jestjs, vuejs3, inertiajs

I am using Inertia.js via using Laravel9.
I tried to test the code below:

```
<script setup>
import { Head, Link, useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import AuthenticationCard from '@/Components/AuthenticationCard.vue';
import AuthenticationCardLogo from '@/Components/AuthenticationCardLogo.vue';
import InputError from '@/Components/InputError.vue';
import InputLabel from '@/Components/InputLabel.vue';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue';
import TextInput from '@/Components/TextInput.vue';

defineProps({
    status: String,
});

const form = useForm({
    email: '',
});

const submit = () => {
    form.post(route('password.email'));
};
</script>
```

Then test code:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import ForgotPassword from '@/Pages/Auth/ForgotPassword.vue';

let wrap;

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  delete: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  wrap = shallowMount(ForgotPassword, {
    props: {
      profiles: [],
    },
  });
});

describe('Sample', () => {
  test('can read email property', () => {
    expect(wrap.vm.form.email).toBe('');
  });
});
```

Running the test results in:

```
 ● Sample › can read email property

    TypeError: (0 , _vue.useForm) is not a function

      12 | });
      13 |
    > 14 | const form = useForm({
         |                     ^
      15 |     email: '',
      16 | });
      17 |
```

However, when I changed import statement `'@inertiajs/vue3'` to `'@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'`,
it worked.

According to the [Inertia.js docs](https://inertiajs.com/upgrade-guide), the latter '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3' is older, so the app doesn't work downgrading @inertiajs/inertia-vue3.

How can I run jest using '@inertiajs/vue3' instead of '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'?